# Facebook getting pages id issue using php

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-iframe, facebook-apps, facebook-page

I have a facebook application and a tab page which links `http://localhost/a/index.php`, I have successfully add this tab page to my `pages`. I wrote in index.php

```
$checkLoggedIn = $facebook->getSignedRequest();
```

it return me like this

```
Array
(
[algorithm] => HMAC-SHA256
[expires] => 1324648800
[issued_at] => 1324644411
[oauth_token] => AAACMkfuFjmIBAEJ9zqtJVvDK08aXlO1wSEFVNvekyCWcZBtnQcJ8BTCYfwZBMyrom5nazjPCsF56v4hLCBi2VywUzgrLSTYr9sbMmTWDN5QFFeOBfU
[page] => Array
    (
        [id] => 309081639123289
        [liked] => 1
        [admin] => 1
    )

[user] => Array
    (
        [country] => bd
        [locale] => en_US
        [age] => Array
            (
                [min] => 21
            )

    )

[user_id] => 1549070809
)
```

its ok for me. I have also another link on that page is `start.php` with same code but it return to me like this

```
Array
(
[algorithm] => HMAC-SHA256
[code] => 2.AQAHgyMnInvOgkoU.3600.1324648800.5-1549070809|OMFOQPTFesejPmg0h2SfwwNGGEY
[issued_at] => 1324644436
[user_id] => 1549070809
)
```

what can I now? to get same object. because they are in same iframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the facebook sdk only saves some information in the session (your second array). To remember the page, you have to manually save it.